# Getting the remote ip address when using nginx proxy for Glang Gin?

Tags: go, nginx, go-gin

I'm using Nginx as a proxy for a golang API app which uses go gin framework 
The Nginx configuration is simple

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Client-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Appengine-Remote-Addr $remote_addr;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade          $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection       upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Accept-Encoding  gzip;
    }
}
```

and Go code is storing the IP address to the database uses

```
ctx.RemoteIP()
```

to get the IP
the problem is that it always stores 127.0.0.1 and never gets the real requested IP
I switched to another function

```
ctx.ClientIP()
```

and the same problem it stores 127.0.0.1 instead of requesting IP

in both methods I did set the trusted proxy to "X-Client-IP"

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.TrustedPlatform = "X-Client-IP"
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pongy",
        })
    })
    r.POST("/signup", controllers.SignUp)
    r.POST("/login", controllers.Login)
    r.GET("/validation", middleware.RequireAuth, controllers.Validation)
    r.Run("127.0.0.1:3000") // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to do two things to fix this.

First, change the header name from `X-Client-IP` to `X-Real-IP` or `X-Forwarded-For`.

Then, set localhost as a trusted proxy like this:

`r.SetTrustedProxies([]string{"127.0.0.1", "::1"})`

Replace the line `r.TrustedPlatform = "X-Client-IP"` with the above, and calls to `ctx.ClientIP()` should return what you're after.

You can see in the [Gin source that it's looking for these two header names](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/cc367f9125516313a4b8d2da1eed5527b5420dbc/gin.go#L192).